# R plotly histogram hover text

Tags: r, plotly

This is my code. Just a simple historgram. But what I wanted to do is to customize the hover text so that when I hover, it will display all species included in that histogram bar. Can you help  me?

```
iris %>% 
  plot_ly(x=~Sepal.Length, color=~Sepal.Width, text=~Species) %>% 
  add_histogram()
```

Here's the output. But when I hover it seems the text is only displaying the first species in the table.
[plotly_hist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HTcF.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is possible. Probably you are demanding too much from plotly. After trying some options I think there are two ways to go if you want the different `Species` to show up in the tooltip:

First option is to use a stacked histogram using `hovermode = "unified"` like so:

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly()

fig <- fig %>% add_trace(data = filter(iris, Species == "setosa"), 
                         x = ~Sepal.Length,
                         color = ~Species,
                         text = ~Species,
                         type='histogram',
                         bingroup=1, showlegend = FALSE)

fig <- fig %>% add_trace(data = filter(iris, Species == "versicolor"),
                         x = ~Sepal.Length,
                         color = ~Species,
                         text = ~Species,
                         type='histogram',
                         bingroup=1, showlegend = FALSE)

fig <- fig %>% add_trace(data = filter(iris, Species == "virginica"),
                         x = ~Sepal.Length,
                         color = ~Species,
                         text = ~Species,
                         type='histogram',
                         bingroup=1, showlegend = FALSE)

fig <- fig %>% layout(
  hovermode="unified",
  barmode="stack",
  bargap=0.1)

fig
```

The second option would be to make the computations yourself, i.e. binning and summarising and to make a bar chart of the counts.

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length.Cut = cut(Sepal.Length, breaks = seq(4, 8, .5), right = FALSE)) %>% 
  group_by(Sepal.Length.Cut, Species) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), Sepal.Width = sum(Sepal.Width)) %>% 
  tidyr::unite("text", Species, n, sep = ": ", remove = FALSE) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n), Sepal.Width = sum(Sepal.Width) / n, text = paste(unique(text), collapse = "\n")) %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~Sepal.Length.Cut, y = ~n, text = ~text) %>% 
  add_bars(marker = list(colorscale = "Rainbow"), hovertemplate = "%{y}<br>%{text}")
```

**Edit** A third option would be to use `ggplotly()`. This way it is an easy task to add annotations displayling the total numbers per bin. This way we can make use of the stats layers in ggplot2 which will do all the computations. To the best of my knowledge that couldn't be done that easily using "pure" plotly.

```
library(plotly)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  stat_bin(breaks = seq(4, 8, .5), closed = "left") +
  stat_bin(breaks = seq(4, 8, .5), closed = "left", geom = "text", mapping = aes(Sepal.Length, label = ..count..), inherit.aes = FALSE, vjust = -.5) +
  theme_light()

ggplotly()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Follow-up. If I do the first answer, how can I customize the data label on top of each bar so that it's value is like in a histogram (count of all items in the bar)?

Comment: Hi @jassybels. Had another look. Unfortunately I found no solution to this problem in except of switching to `ggplotly`. This way you can make use of all the magic of ggplot2 and still have an interacitve plotly chart. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: Hi Stefan, can you please take a look at my question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161597/gluing-graphs-together-trouble-with-traces-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic thank you